# Unix Domain Socket Server only prints message when client closes

Tags: sockets, unix, rust

I'm trying to implement a Unix Domain Socket Server in Rust, which lets a client connect, then the client sends a message through the socket and the server prints it. However, the server doesn't print the message until I close (CTLR + C) the client process. What could the problem be? Here are both the codes:

Server:

```
use std::thread;
use std::os::unix::net::{UnixStream, UnixListener};
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};

fn main() {
    let listener = UnixListener::bind("/tmp/socket.sock").unwrap();

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        match stream {
            Ok(mut stream) => {
                println!("Client connected!");
                thread::spawn(move ||  {
                    let mut out = String::new();
                    let mut bf = BufReader::new(stream);
                    bf.read_line(&mut out);
                    println!("{}", out);
                });
            } Err(err) => {
                println!("Connection failed!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Client:

```
use std::os::unix::net::{UnixStream, UnixListener};
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::io::{BufWriter};

fn main() {
    let mut stream = UnixStream::connect("/tmp/socket.sock").unwrap();
    let mut bf = BufWriter::new(&stream);

    bf.write_all("Hello server".as_bytes());
    bf.flush();
    drop(bf);
}
```

I tried it with the read_to_string method too, but it simply doesn't print until the client closes. Does anyone have any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

```rust
bf.read_line(&mut out);
```

Your read code reads *lines*. But your sending code doesn't send a line. So the read code continues to try to read a line as you asked it to do. When the connection is closed, the read code can no longer try to read a line, so it returns.

You have to implement the same protocol on both sides. If the reader understands line endings to be message boundaries, then the writer must place a line ending at each point you want the receiving code to understand a message to end.

By the way, it's really a good idea to document any protocol you're going to layer on top of a network protocol, at least until you get much more experienced. That would have avoided this kind of mistake. Either the protocol would say that messages consist of lines or it would say they consist of something else, and that would make it clear which side is wrong and which is right.

As it is now, neither side is wrong or right. They just disagree. Those mistakes are completely avoided by proper protocol documentation. Is the protocol these two programs are using to communicate with each other line-based? Or not? You need documentation to know. It's worth the effort to document.

Comment: i'm planning on defining a protocol, but am just testing things out for now. if i understand correctly, the problem is that the line never ends? i'll try adding an endline character at the end then...